# Calculate \$ \lfloor n \log_2(n) \rfloor \$, exactly

Tags: code-golf, math, number, integer

Given an integer \$ n \ge 2 \$, you need to calculate \$ \lfloor n \log_2(n) \rfloor \$, assuming all integers in your language are unbounded.

However, you may **not** ignore floating-point errors - for example, in python `lambda n:int(n*math.log2(n))` is an invalid solution, because for example for `n=10**15`, `int(n*math.log2(n))` is 49828921423310432, while the actual answer is 49828921423310435.

### Rules

- You can assume the input is an integer \$ n \ge 2 \$
- You may use any [reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed

### Test cases

```
2 -> 2
3 -> 4
4 -> 8
5 -> 11
6 -> 15
7 -> 19
8 -> 24
9 -> 28
10 -> 33
100 -> 664
1000 -> 9965
10000 -> 132877
```

10 brownie points for beating my 4 byte 05AB1E answer.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins. Good luck!

Comment: This is [OEIS A326299](https://oeis.org/A326299).

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:len(bin(n**n))-3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvLCkBAGIbhvav4sxr6lPOpuBEsCJniG8nG1Y@pd/f03t97GGZ270Z7zteyzsL23KgWTcUwZBBETs0jFE0ZUmTIUaBEhRoNktgVT60n96P5KkL8qPchu3Kr/QE)

If the answer is \$x\$, then \$x+1 > n\log{n} \ge x\$ holds true, which means \$2^{x+1} > n^n \ge 2^x\$. So we can simply count the number of bits in the binary representation of \$n^n\$.

Comment: Have you tested it for big numbers? Because I tried `10^7` (not on the TIO, on the PC), which isn't even that big and the execution took like 2-3 minutes. Does it still work for `10^100` mentioned under other of answers?

Comment: @elementiro This is code golf, so as long as it works in theory the answer is valid.  If it fails because of timing out or out-of-memory errors, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ebL‹
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=ebL%E2%80%B9&inputs=10000&header=&footer=)

Translation of @ManishKundu's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226215/98955).

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
*`BL’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18rwcnnUcPM////GxoAAQA)

Ditto.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/iki/Code-page)

```
*ḃ2L
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer, \$n>1\$, that yields \$ \lfloor n \log_2(n) \rfloor \$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r4Y5mI5//h9sfNa35/z/aSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHQsdSx9AAiMAYQhjEAgA)**

#### How?

As noted by [Manish Kundu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226215/53748) the answer is one less than the number of binary digits of \$n^n\$.

This can be achieved in Jelly in five bytes in a few ways one of which is: `*b2L’`.

Note, however, that \$n^n=2^x-1\$ has no integer solutions except \$n=x=1\$ (see [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n%5En%3D2%5Ex-1%2Cx%3E1%2Cn%3E1+over+the+integers)*) and that the [bijective base two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) representation of a number always has one less digit than the standard base two representation except when the number is of the form \$2^k-1\$ (when both representations are identical, a string of \$k\$ ones).

Since \$n=1\$ is invalid input we can, therefore, count the number of digits in the bijective base two representation of \$n^n\$.

```
*ḃ2L - Link: integer, n
*    - (n) exponentiate (n) -> n^n
  2  - two
 ḃ   - (n^n) in bijective base (2)
   L - length
```

* if someone has a proof, I'll happily put it here!

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
X$tZl*k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9pIwVjBRMFUwUzBXMFCwVLB0ACIwBhGIoHYCJWSqByt7P//AQ)

```
X$tZl*k
X$       - sym, implicit input
  t      - duplicate top of stack and push it
   Zl    - log2
     *   - multiply
      k  - floor
```

This is just what [elementiro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98428/elementiro) did except in golfed MATLAB, and since this is my first time posting, I am not sure if this is considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```ruby
->n{/.$/=~"%b"%n**n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWl9PRd@2Tkk1SUk1T0srr/Z/gUJatFEsF4gygVCGBkAQ@x8A)

Get the length of the binary string representation of n^n.
Basically uses the same formula as Manish Kundu and everybody else after him.

Using `bit_width` or `digits(2).size` would make it longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <s>18</s> 24 bytes

```julia
n->ndigits(n^n,base=2)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LCsIwEEX38xVD3STQgnm0TRbpwp3fIAqVthIpozQR/PuYFGdxzxkYmPv8rH4U37S4RM1Ak3/4GBjdqL6PYXaSNyLFOcSADk/@caZ4AYkHlKByatA5DbQ5hYCuoIW@wIIpZxpsgQFxzFQqs0jX6WJFre3a3csilDR9D1eA5bVhRE@4fwfM8948xZVYrLFCN2BV/yuxhUXOOcw0pR8)

port of [Manish Kundu's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226215/98541)

#### previous answer:

```julia
n->floor(log2(n)n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LCoMwEEX38xWD3Riw4ORlstBFd/2G0kKhRiwhFk2hf28zzuKec2EY5v2N85N@e@j3dB5CXJa1jssk6ySS2PO45Q17vMzTNeUbSDyhBFVSgy7pwJQkAssw0DE8OF7T4BkOqC1UqpDFWs3G6r01h3MhJV3Xlfogvqm9k85L0lIparUycAcIy4oZ54THX4BlPuucckx1brDCfsCqwVBnIWBMr/0P)

input needs to be a `BigInt` to avoid floating point errors.

Technically invalid because you need to augment the precision for very big numbers (with `setprecision(2048)` for example for `10^100`)

Comment: The output is wrong for `BigInt(10)^100`.

Comment: what is the right answer ?

Comment: 3321928094887362347870319429489390175864831393024580612054756395815934776608625215850139743359370155099

Comment: It will work by increasing the precision, but you can always find a bigger number that won't work [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzNbsIwEITveYo9Jq2Q9sdr7x4c8SRIbUUgKLIRaUXePvhAjzPfN3P7W@Yv2vYp7@UwTkutj36pF@7LUIZ9Pf/eH@efeZ1r6RmDDV2BDN/zpSccToTYbS1Pze6O67U@YfskGKF8vD9gzLD9I8gZRJicDT2YJYksIVlCIQ/cKhdHSmoxmJC4IAc1jMSoIWkUVyP1tkkxokVWJjXFpqYg0khCUkX3/QU "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: is it ok if I restrict the ouput to Int64 like this ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZDLagMxDEX3@gqTbmYgLXpYtrRIFl0U@g2lgUCTMGXwlMSF/v3UTqvFPVcPC6PP73k60s963q3lcX@el@U6vJa6nZcLD2Us41pPt3oLu/A8XVrjDTg8BAZpGiE2NdCmRJA6FHKHg/WxCN5hQNgo0thNSrG7bt2T3n1PSNhybumB@s7oxuZMkUUIoyi0P7zMy7EOhE84Hv62iTA5G3o0y5JYYraMQh65lVwcKaulaELighzVMBGjxqxJXI3U25ucElpiZVJTbKM5irRORlJFd3gHOC/XUMNUwv0oEFp8XadS5zLUbdiE3T5stv@XGs5DHccRTuVj/QU "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: or I could use the same approach as the others but it restricts even more the maximal number possible [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZDLagMxDEX3@grTbmYgKdbLlhbJootCv6E0kJIHU4JTMi7076d2Wi3uubIeGH1@X6Y9/iynzVLW23KYzlOdh7Irq4/9fNzQuMalHuc6h014ns6vpb4BhcdAwE0FpKmBNkWE1KGQOxystwl4hwHGRubGblKS7rp1T3r3PUEmy7mlO@w7xY3MCYWYMQortD@8XK77OmB8iuPubxszoZNFF7PMiViy5cjoQu3J2SNmtSTGyM6RRC0mpKiSNbGroXqbySlFS6SEahpbaxbmVskRVaM7vAOcrrdQw1TC/SgQWnzdplIvZair8BA22/Cw@r/UcBrqOI5wLIflFw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes (11 characters)

```
⌊#*Log2@#⌋&
```

-2 thanks to [ZaMoC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67961/zamoc)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1FPl7KWT366kYPyo55utf8BRZl5JdHKunZp0cqxsWoK@g4K1YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWOoYGOgqGBnGGprX/AQ)

Comment: How can you be sure this won't FPE eventually?

Comment: In Mathematica these calculations are exact, no floating-point approximations involved and therefore no overflows and limitations. Just try `f[10^10^6]` for fun!

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1FPl09@upGDspbyo55utf8BRZl5JdHKunZp0cqxsWoK@g4K1YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWOoYGOgqGBnGGprX/AQ "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

Same approach as [Manish Kundu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226215/58563).

Expects a BigInt.

```javascript
n=>(g=n=>n?g(n/2n)+1:-1)(n**n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9DoIwFIbhnav4xh48IMV/STExcfAajANBWjHk1ABxMV57xTi8z/g@qlc11H37HBPxtyZYE8SUyplJOTgl81xopveJJiVxLBSKC3LGgrFkrBhrxoaxZewYOvv1J8M1Sq3vT1V9VwJT4h0BtZfBd03a@WnNsOrYurOMSoioiD4Uvg)

Comment: Crashes on 10000 :(

Comment: `n=>(n**n).toString(2).length-1` seems to work for 10000 for the same byte count.

Comment: `g(n/2n)` <- Another wtf js behavior here

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbignum -p`, 24 bytes

```perl
$_=int$_*(1*$_)->blog(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYzr0QlXkvDUEslXlPXLiknP13DSPP/f0MDIPiXX1CSmZ9X/F/XNykzPa80979uQQ4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
Ｉ⊖Ｌ↨Ｘθθ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyU1uSg1NzWvJDVFwyc1L70kQ8MpsThVIyC/PLVIo1BHoVBTR8FIEwSs//83NDAw@K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the same identity \$ \lfloor n \log_2 n \rfloor = \lfloor \log_2 n^n \rfloor \$ as everyone else. (Exponentially slow for large `n` of course, so stick to 4 digit inputs for testing on TIO.) Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @CommandMaster.

Comment: Since unary output is allowed by default, can't it be 9 bytes?

Comment: `⊖Ｌ↨Ｘθθ²` seems to work for 7 bytes?

Comment: @CommandMaster Huh, I didn't realise that Power casts its arguments to number first, thanks. I don't think unary output is reasonable though (even for Retina I prefer to use decimal I/O when I can).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 4 bytes

```
mbg<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Nynd5v9/QwMDAwA)

Comment: Why is this legacy?

Comment: @Makonede It's an old version of the language

Comment: @LuisMendo I know. That's not my question. My question is why use legacy when you can use the rewrite?

Comment: @makonede it doesn't quite matter

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
tl.B^
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=tl.B%5E&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A100%0A1000%0A10000&debug=0)

A near literal translation of [Manish Kundu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77516/manish-kundu)['s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226215/78186).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>52</s> \$\cdots\$<s>35</s></sup> 23 bytes

Saved 8 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)!!!

```c
f(n){n=logb(pow(n,n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDbboMwDH3vV1hI1RIa1HIpLWPsZdpXrH2gwbRoNFQkUtEqfn3MUIbWRbKVHPscx0c6Rym7LmeK31RSVscDu1RXpoTiPG67Qhk4p4VifHabAZ0eMKiN/thDAjdPgC8gELAWEArYCNgKiAS4qz7uacyrNp4UsLmgNJhNIsFAdF0KUnJJwSPII8wn/TAM2hiWNviecyhML6FBpurJwClVWYlgTqjxGaIo7Om@t91siGEvh4nylNY2ZZSfWNNI6Idau@bd2zXRG8XaEvD37VvjX/OqBtZ/uFAZNkRbxeP1BXTxhVXOflfhyxGwJySGxWLo5nA3bzKQlO4mDuV9/FDVVM2Z4Y8oEjrZ9p92qaklZ9Y8A@cVKM/1TtFSRoAW0@aYJHo/yraztvuWeZkededcO6c8/wA)

Uses the formula from [Manish Kundu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77516/manish-kundu)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226215/9481).

Comment: [`f(n){n=logb(pow(n,n));}`](https://tio.run/##RY1BCoMwFET3nmKwFH5QCy3u1J6kmzQ2@iEmQVNciFdvGumii2GGx4NR1aBUjJq82Hxn3PAk71bypRei2eOJrTLv/oV2kmG8jPfsT5bQszsQ24BJsiWBLQO0m0EHY3S4NalaXOs6jaL4GYCfk6ApP/ePkGLzElxCE6fXJOzZHj9KGzkssTJTrNYv)

Comment: @tsh Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: Isn't `pow` a floating-point function?

Comment: @CommandMaster IEEE754 floating point number have more bits for fraction than exponent. And it use binary as its representation. So it always yield correct result as long as `pow(n,n)` not exceed the limit of the floating point type (not yield +inf). And the same algorithm may be extend to larger IEEE754 floating types such as binary256 (if the compiler support it). The question disallow floating point _errors_, but not floating point _functions_.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 36 bytes

```java
n->n.pow(n.intValue()).bitLength()-1
```

Accepts a `BigInteger` as input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZI/a8MwEMVn61NolEp90P8tSTN0KBRaOgS6lAyKIyty5JOwzi4h5LO7SjG0a3XL497j9265Rg2qbDa70bbBd8SbtENP1kHdY0XWI5zN/matom2yWOjXzla8cipG/qYs8gPjaSY/kqIkg7cb3qZULKmzaD5XqjNRHljxPNXPn6x5QdJGd@eTLurHEcsFQvBfAsEifSjXayElrC29ajS0FbK8GIsZK5b7SLoF3xOEdIEcihpUCG4vfpthOBW81@JSSvlv6CoHus6BbnKg2xzoLge6z4EefqDTaxzZcfwG)

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/Octave, 30 bytes

```matlab
@(x)floor(sym(x)*log2(sym(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMy0nP79Io7gyF8jWyslPN4KyNTX/pynYKiTmFVtzpWlk5pWYmWgYaWrC2cZIbBMktikS2wyJbY7EtkBiWyKxDQ1QOGg8dC4qP84QZPN/AA)
Anonymous function.
The result is symbolic number but can be easily cast to any other type.
This solution works as long as the upper bound of `int64` allows it.

---

Technically, much better solution is
`@(x)floor(x*log2((x)))`
(which is  **20 bytes** btw) with symbolic input. Since the question says input is integer I couldn't use it though. Because our input is unbounded it works for much much bigger numbers (I managed to calculate 10<sup>1 000 000</sup> but the calculations took a while and the output in console was truncated, for too big numbers throws an error though). I encourage anyone to check the result for 10<sup>300</sup> if their method is capable of working for such big inputs:

```
f(sym(10^300)) =
 
996578428466208704361095828846817052759449417907374183616426918744780432982587564755041923007811046529897211513075075548047229095279058066482590831899596618155585405797251670592905282757007467500082430012203570937256212532914759940262053756896742020749233906529817764982497756734670715067992925218241378
```

<sub><sub><sub><sub>*...did I mention unlike some of the other answers this takes only ~0.05s for MATLAB to calculate even for that big inputs?*</sub></sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
ṖɓąŁ⁻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//4c5pJycfaT3a@Khx9///hgZAAAA)

```
ṖɓąŁ⁻
Ṗ        implicit input (n); raise n to the nth power
 ɓ       convert to binary string
  ąŁ     convert string to array of characters and get length
    ⁻    subtract one; implicit print
```

Port of [Manish Kundu's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226214/calculate-lfloor-n-log-2n-rfloor-exactly/226215#226215)